# Wordpress: Как сделать дополнительный урл для каждого поста?

Tags: wordpress

Есть такая структура:

```
example.com/product/12345
```

product - custom post-type,
12345 - post slug.
Мне нужно для каждого поста сделать дополнительный /go линк (example.com/product/12345/go) при переходе на который будет редиректить на урл взятый из мета-данных у этого же поста.
Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
В functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'go_redirect');
function go_redirect() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'product\/([\d]*)\/go$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&redirect=1', 'top' );
    add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
        $vars[] = 'redirect';
        return $vars;
    } );
}
```

В начале single.php вставляем следующий код:

```
<?php 
$go = get_query_var('redirect');
$post_id = $post->ID;
if ($go) {header('Location: ' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'redirect_url', true), true, 301);}
?>
```